# Efficient SearchView suggestions in Android

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, performance, searchview

I have a SearchView in my ActionBar, displaying suggestions as the user types characters.
My suggestions are stored in a String ArrayList like this:

```
private ArrayList<String> mSuggestions;
```

Then my search function displays suggestions based on the queried text.

```
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    mSuggestions.clear();
    for(MyObject o : mObjects)
        if(o.getName().contains(newText))
            mSuggestions.add(o.getName());

    return false;
}
```

It has **O(n)** efficiency, because it iterates over the array searching for the queried word. So when mSuggestions.size() grows, it becomes slow and unefficient.

I'd like to use another container, more efficient than the ArrayList, to make the search **O(log(n))**, but haven't found the most adequate one.

Does someone have any suggestion for that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To get really efficient results you could look at a SQLite FTS3 Virtual Table but it's complex and takes time to build the table for the first time depending on the number of DB records. Google for FTS3. I think the Android dev site also has an example of how to use it.

Comment: Sounds Interesting. What i was searching for was something at a higher level, like using another container instead of the ArrayList, or any algorithm. Thanks for your response tho.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing a substring search, you may consider using a HashMap that maps every possible substring to a list of objects that contain the substring (`HashMap<String, List<MyObject>>`). This assumes your `mObjects` list is not updated for each query (e.g. if you were doing a network request to load results based on the query) and you are able to precompute the data structure which remains more or less static. Then your lookups will be done in O(1) but you'd pay in space efficiency to store all the substrings. Your code would look like:

```
private Map<String, List<MyObject>> mObjectLookupMap = 
    new HashMap<String, List<MyObject>>();

// precompute lookup map with all possible substrings

public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    mSuggestions.clear();

    if (mObjectLookupMap.containsKey(newText)) {
       for (MyObject o : mObjectLookupMap.get(newText))
         mSuggestions.add(o.getName());
    }

    return false;
}
```

A more space efficient solution might be to use a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) to store the substrings. Then your lookup time would be in order with the longest MyObject name (i.e. the depth of the substring tree).